# Ubtuntu 18.04 Software "cannot resolve hostname"

Tags: apt, 18.04, software-center, hostname

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu Software gives me the following error:
    Unable to download updates from "extensions.gnome.org": [*/*/*/source/shell-extensions/*] failed to download https://extensions.gnome.org//static/extensions.json: Cannot resolve hostname

I tried running    sudo apt-get update    and    sudo apt-get upgrade    which worked fine, but the problem persists.

Comment: please check your nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf, this need maybe to be added or adjusted there temporary and in netplan permanently